# Highcharts - Lazy loading combined with SQL queries

Tags: sql, ajax, lazy-loading, highcharts

Based on the [Lazy Loading Example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading) I wanted to create the similar function for my Highcharts.StockChart. But with the aid of Ajax.

Some words about the database structure:

- Tables contains the values of 1 month
- Column 'tijd' contains a timestamp
- Values are posted every minute to the database, resolution = 1 minute

Please focus on why the zoom function isn't updating the chart. This drives me #!#

For the first time generation of the chart I use this code, which works fine
*JAVASCRIPT:*

```
function generateChart(param, options)
        {
            // EERST DE GESELECTEERDE GEGEVENS GAAN OPVRAGEN
            data = param.join();
            console.log(data);
            t_min = new Date(2015, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            t_max = Date.now();
            console.log(t_min, t_max);
            console.log((t_max - t_min) / 1000);
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { "data": data, "db": klantnummer, "t_min": t_min, "t_max": t_max },
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success:
                        function (gegevens)
                        {
                            // GEGEVENS OPSLAAN IN DE OPTIE.SERIES
                            console.log('Gegevens:');
                            console.log(gegevens); //werkt!
                            options.series = gegevens;
                        }
            });
            //EFFECTIEF AANMAKEN VAN DE GRAFIEK
            chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);
        }
```

*PHP:*

```
// READ THE COLUMN NAMES
$data_in = $_POST['data'];

// DATA_IN to array
$name = explode(",", $data_in);

// count the amount of columns
$c_name = count($name);
$name_sql = implode(", ", $name);

//Connection with database
$klantnummer = $_POST['db'];
require 'connectie.php';

//ZOOM: min and max values are converterd to PHP UNIX EPOCH time
$t_min = ($_POST['t_min'])/1000;
$t_max = ($_POST['t_max'])/1000;
$range = $t_max - $t_min;

//Doesn't work, don't need it to load the chart
//$startTime = $t_min->format('m-d-Y H:i:s');
//$stopTime = $t_max->format('m-d-Y H:i:s');

//we only ask a query if there are enough columns
if ($c_name > 0) {
    //Ask the names of the tables from the database
    $sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'T%' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC";

    $tableName = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    if ( $tableName === false ) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    };
    $t = array();
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($tableName)) {
        array_push($t, $row['TABLE_NAME']);
    };

    // So we know the range, which filter should we apply?
    if ($range < 14 * 24 *3600) {       //2 weeks
        $tijdspanne = 2;                    // load 2 tables
        $filter = 1;                        // show every minute
    } elseif ($range < 28 * 24 *3600) { //4 weeks
        $tijdspanne = 2;                    // load 2 tables
        $filter = 5;                        // show every 5 minutes    
    } elseif ($range < 3 * 28 * 24 *3600) { //3 months
        $tijdspanne = 4;                    // load 4 months
        $filter = 15;                       // show every 15 minutes    
    } else {
        $tijdspanne = count($t); // load every table
        $filter = 60; // show every 60 minutes    
    }

    //Namen zijn gekend, nu in query steken om daarna op te vragen
    $sql = "select tijd,".$name_sql." FROM ".$t[0]." where datepart(mi,tijd) % ".$filter." = 0";// AND tijd BETWEEN ".$startTime." AND ".$stopTime;

    for ($x = 1; $x < count($t) and $x < $tijdspanne ; ++$x ) {
        $sql .= " union all select tijd,".$name_sql." FROM ".$t[$x]." where datepart(mi,tijd) % ".$filter." = 0";// AND tijd BETWEEN ".$startTime." AND ".$stopTime;
    };
    $sql .= " ORDER BY tijd";

    //DATA from MS SQL server, save to arrays
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    if ( $stmt === false ) {
         die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
        $tijd_U = $row["0"]->format("U");
        $tijd = ($tijd_U) * 1000;  //date format to javascript
        for ($i = 0; $i < $c_name; ++$i) {
            $j = $i +1;
            $data[$i][]= array($tijd, $row[$j]);
        }
    }

    // prepare JSON format
    $data_output = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c_name; ++$i) {
        $data_output[$i] = array('name' => $name[$i], 'data' => $data[$i]);
    }
}

// admit we use JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// send the data to the user
echo json_encode($data_output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

So this code works, but when the user zooms in. The graph doens't update.

*JAVASCRIPT:*

```
function afterSetExtremes(e)
        {
            console.log(Math.round(e.min));
            chart.showLoading('Loading data from server...');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { "data": data, "db": klantnummer, "t_min": Math.round(e.min), "t_max": Math.round(e.max) },
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success:
                        function (gegevens)
                        {
                            // GEGEVENS OPSLAAN IN DE OPTIE.SERIES
                            console.log('Gegevens:');
                            console.log(gegevens); //werkt!
                            options.series = gegevens;
                        }
            });


            chart.hideLoading();

        }
```

With this set of options:

```
function generateChartOptions(div, ymax, ymin)
            {
                var options = {
                    navigator: {
                        adaptToUpdatedData: false,
                        series: {
                            includeInCSVExport: false
                        }
                    },
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: div,
                        type: 'line',
                        zoomType: 'x'
                    },
                    rangeSelector: {
                        buttons: [{
                            type: 'day',
                            count: 1,
                            text: '1d'
                        }, {
                            type: 'week',
                            count: 1,
                            text: '1w'
                        }, {
                            type: 'week',
                            count: 2,
                            text: '2w'
                        }, {
                            type: 'all',
                            text: 'All'
                        }],
                        selected: 4,
                        inputBoxWidth: 150,
                        inputDateFormat: '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M',
                        inputEditDateFormat: '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        events: {
                            afterSetExtremes: afterSetExtremes,
                            setExtremes: function (e)
                            {
                                $('#testveld').html('<b>Set extremes:</b> e.min: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat(null, e.min) +
                                            ' | e.max: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat(null, e.max) + ' | e.trigger: ' + e.trigger);
                            }
                        },
                        minRange: 60 * 1000 //1 minuut
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        opposite: false,
                        max: ymax,
                        min: ymin
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        line: {
                            tooltip: {
                                valueDecimals: 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    scrollbar: {
                        liveRedraw: false
                    },
                    series: [{}]
                };
                return options;
            }
```

Comment: Open [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/). You will see that `afterSetExtremes` is different. Changing `options.series` does nothing, you should be using `chart.series[index].setData(new_data)`.

Comment: Could you specify the demo you mentioned?

Comment: Also, do I have to make a for each function around the chart.series() ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake when copying link, [this one](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading) is proper one. And yes, if you have multiple series, then you need to update each of them. Remember to set `redraw=false` to avoid multiple redraws, and redraw chart after updating all the series.

Comment: Okey, that's clear.
I noticed that the chart isn't showing the loading phrase ... could you help me with this too?

Comment: Just follow the example I sent you. If that demo works, then compare code, something must be different ;)

Comment: `var len = gegevens.length;
                                console.log(gegevens, len); //werkt!
                                for (i = 0; i < len; i++ )
                                {
                                    chart.series[i].setData(gegevens[i], false);
                                }
                                chart.redraw();`
Now the chart isn't loading the new values ... just gives a blank.

Comment: Also, my data is a `[[timestamp1,value1],[timestamp1,value1],...]` array. Does this has an influence to the `chart.series[i]`?

Comment: How your `gegevens` looks like is more important. Could you show an example? I guess there should be `gegevens[i].data`.

Comment: `Object {name: "TT_009", data: Array[9455]}`  
Your `gegevens[i].data` did the trick!!!